# select table from other schema

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a table from schema "test":

```
class AttributeConversion(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test.attribute_conversion'
```

How to select records from this table?

SQLAlchemy generates SQL:

```
select * from "test.attribute_conversion"
```

But it doesn't work. The correct query must be:

```
select * from test.attribute_conversion  (without quotes)
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can explicity specify a schema name for a table:

```
class AttributeConversion(Base)
    __tablename__ = 'attribute_conversion'
    __table_args__ = {'schema' : 'test'}
```

See documentation on [specifying the schema name](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#specifying-the-schema-name).