# Cross database join in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Is there a way in SQLAlchemy to do cross-database joins. To be specific, here is my use case:

**Schema**

1. db1.entity1

   1. entity1_id: Primary Key
   2. entity2_id: Foreign Key to db2.entity2.entity2_id
2. db2.entity2

   1. entity2_id: Primary Key

**Model**

I'm using *declarative style* for models.

```
class Entity1(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'entity1' ## I tried combination of <db>.<table> with no success
  entity1_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  entity2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('db2.entity2.entity2_id'))
  entity2 = relationship('Entity2')

class Entity2(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'entity2' ## I tried combination of <db>.<table> with no success
  entity2_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Now, as expected, my queries for Entity1 is failing with MySQL error messages saying table entity2 not found. I tried many different combination for `__tablename__` with no success. So i was wondering if it is possible in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6017895/7232335

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You probably need to pass the `schema` parameter to `sqlalchemy.schema.Table`.  When using declarative base for ORM mapping, you can provide this extra parameter through the `__table_args__` property on your classes.

```
class Entity2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entity2' ## I tried combination of <db>.<table> with no success
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'db2'}
    entity2_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) 

class Entity1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entity1' ## I tried combination of <db>.<table> with no success
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'db1'}
    entity1_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    entity2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Entity2.entity2_id))
    entity2 = relationship('Entity2')
```

Comment: If you come across this and are using SQL Server, note that you can provide the DB and schema simultaneously by applying `__table_args__ = {'schema': 'db2.dbo'}` (substituting `dbo` if the schema is not the default).  More info: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#multipart-schema-names