# python sqlalchemy combine query from two tables

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have two tables that are not related like this:

```
hurst = Table('Hurst', metadata,
    Column('symbol_id' , Integer, primary_key=True), 
    Column('Date'      , String(20), nullable=False),
    Column('symbol'    , String(40), nullable=False),
    Column('HurstExp'  , Float,      nullable=False),
)

fundamental = Table('Fundamental', metadata,
    Column('symbol_id' , Integer,    primary_key=True), 
    Column('Date'      , String(20), nullable=False),
    Column('symbol'    , String(40), nullable=False),
    Column('MarketCap' , Float,      nullable=False),
)
```

Each of the following queries works fine. How do I combine them so I can get **only** the hurst of companies that are worth more than 50,000,000,000?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Dec 13 19:22:35 2015

@author: idf
"""

from sqlalchemy import *

def run(stmt):
    rs = stmt.execute()
    return rs

# Let's re-use the same database as before
dbh = create_engine('sqlite:///hurst.db')
dbf = create_engine('sqlite:///fundamental.db')

dbh.echo = True  # We want to see the SQL we're creating
dbf.echo = True  # We want to see the SQL we're creating

metadatah = MetaData(dbh)
metadataf = MetaData(dbf)

# The users table already exists, so no need to redefine it. Just
# load it from the database using the "autoload" feature.
hurst = Table('Hurst',       metadatah, autoload=True)
funda = Table('Fundamental', metadataf, autoload=True)

hurstQ = hurst.select(hurst.c.HurstExp < .5)
run(hurstQ)

fundaQ = funda.select(funda.c.MarketCap > 50000000000)
run(fundaQ)
```

If I try to use a join, I get an error:

```
j = join(hurst, funda, hurst.c.symbol == funda.c.symbol)
stmt = select([hurst]).select_from(j)
theJoin = run(stmt)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/idf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/idf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 450, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

   cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Fundamental
```

I can't even do the easy version

```
# This will return more results than you are probably expecting.
s = select([hurst, funda])
run(s)
```

Comment: See the edited post. The tables are seperate. Maybe I need to relate them somehow but the two tables are created seperately.

Comment: You need to can use the `backref` feature of `sqlalchemy` and create a reference of the other table using a foreign key or relation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have an environment to test this in at the moment, but something along the lines of this should work:

```
j = join(husrt, funda, (hurst.c.symbol_id == funda.c.symbol_id) & (funda.c.MarketCap > 50000000000))
stmt = select([hurst]).select_from(j)
run(stmt)
```

Check out `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.join` on [this SQL Alchemy docs page.](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.CompoundSelect)

Comment: See the edited post. Even something this simple doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can join between two **databases**.

One of your tables is in one database and the other is in another database:

```
dbh = create_engine('sqlite:///hurst.db')
dbf = create_engine('sqlite:///fundamental.db')
```

You should put all tables in the same `database.db` file and have one `db = create_engine('sqlite:///database.db')` .

**Correction:** You can do that: [Cross database join in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433592/cross-database-join-in-sqlalchemy)

But do you really want to have each table in a separate database?