# Get the schema name of an SQLAlchemy ORM class

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have an SQLAlchemy ORM class (not instance). How would I access the name of the table schema?

To my understanding there are two ways to define the schema:

- the [`__table_args__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6027055/9253013) attribute or via
- passing a custom [`MetaData`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData) object to [`declarative_base`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base)

For example if I have a model named `User` doing:

```
# only works for the first method
User.__table_args__['schema']

# only works for the second method and its not deterministic (can be overwritten)
User.metadata.schema
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all cases you can simply access

```
User.__table__.schema
```

to retrieve the schema name, as an optional [`quoted_name`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.elements.quoted_name).