# SQLAlchemist and Oracle: ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Tags: oracle, sqlalchemy

I have this code snippet:

```
ora_engine = create_engine(
    f'oracle+cx_oracle://{user}:{pwd}@{dsn}',
    echo=True, max_identifier_length=30)
ora_engine.connect()

OraSession = sessionmaker(bind=ora_engine)
ora_session = OraSession()

Base = declarative_base()

class AbcdefgAttrib(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ABCDEFGH_ABCDEF.ABCDEFG_ATTRIBUTE'

    batchid = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    value_date = Column(DateTime)
    attribute_name = Column(String)
    attribute_value = Column(String)

query = ora_session.query(AbcdefgAttrib).filter(
    AbcdefgAttrib.attribute_name == 'Bendereszes').distinct('batchid')

print('query:\n' + str(query.statement.compile(dialect=oracle.dialect())))
print(query.values('batchid', 'attribute_name'))
```

This generates me the following SQL:

```
query:
SELECT DISTINCT "ABCDEFGH_ABCDEF.ABCDEFG_ATTRIBUTE".batchid, "ABCDEFGH_ABCDEF.ABCDEFG_ATTRIBUTE".value_date, "ABCDEFGH_ABCDEF.ABCDEFG_ATTRIBUTE".attribute_name, "ABCDEFGH_ABCDEF.ABCDEFG_ATTRIBUTE".attribute_value 
FROM "ABCDEFGH_ABCDEF.ABCDEFG_ATTRIBUTE" 
WHERE "ABCDEFGH_ABCDEF.ABCDEFG_ATTRIBUTE".attribute_name = :attribute_name_1

2020-05-20 13:20:41,224 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2020-05-20 13:20:41,225 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT DISTINCT batchid, attribute_name 
FROM "ABCDEFGH_ABCDEF.ABCDEFG_ATTRIBUTE" 
WHERE "ABCDEFGH_ABCDEF.ABCDEFG_ATTRIBUTE".attribute_name = :attribute_name_1
2020-05-20 13:20:41,225 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'attribute_name_1': 'Bendereszes'}
```

Which gives this Oracle Server error: `sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00972: identifier is too long`

I have checked the following code with `cx_Oracle`:

```
sql = dedent("""
    SELECT DISTINCT batchid, value_date, attribute_name, attribute_value
    FROM "ABCDEFGH_ABCDEF.ABCDEFG_ATTRIBUTE"
    WHERE "ABCDEFGH_ABCDEF.ABCDEFG_ATTRIBUTE".attribute_name = 'Bendereszes'""")
with con.cursor() as cursor:
    row = cursor.execute(sql).fetchone()
    print(row)
```

This gives exactly the same error: `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00972: identifier is too long`

**But when I remove the quoting from the table name, it is working:**

```
sql = dedent("""
    SELECT DISTINCT batchid, value_date, attribute_name, attribute_value
    FROM ABCDEFGH_ABCDEF.ABCDEFG_ATTRIBUTE
    WHERE ABCDEFGH_ABCDEF.ABCDEFG_ATTRIBUTE.attribute_name = 'Bendereszes'""")
with con.cursor() as cursor:
    row = cursor.execute(sql).fetchone()
    print(row)
```

output: `('Lapcsanka', None, 'Bendereszes', 'Boszorka')`

I have read the bible here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/oracle.html
Unfortunately I didn't find solution.

**Is there any way to tell SQLAlchemy, to not quote table names?**
(lower-casing table name didn't help)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have a table name with a `.` in it? That will always require quoting not matter if upper or lower case

Comment: Than why is it working with raw `cx_Oracle` without quoting?

Comment: If you have a table name that contains a `.` there is no way you can use it without double quotes.

Comment: For the unquoted version to be working that isn't a simple table name; `ABCDEFGH_ABCDEF` is the schema name and `ABCDEFG_ATTRIBUTE` is the table name - right? In which case, rather than trying to remove the quotes (you may still need quoted identifiers), it would be better/safer to specify the schema through metadata - [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6027055/266304).